# jQuery selectors - choose element with class that ends in same number

Tags: jquery

I had no idea how to search for what I'm looking for... But I'll try my best to explain it.

I have the following jquery that does the following:

When you click on **.lightbox-trigger-1** it opens up the element with class **.lightbox-content-1** in a lightbox. When you click on element with class **lightbox-trigger-2** it opens up the element with class **lighbox-content-2**, and same with lightbox-trigger-3, 4, 5, and so on.

This is the code I'm using, but I'm sure there is a better way to write this so that regardless of the number (or even a word) after "lightbox-trigger-" it will only open the element that has the same number (or word) after "lightbox-content-". I hope this makes sense...

QUESTION: How can I write this so that there will be a limitless number of lightboxes (not just 10)?

```
$('.lightbox-trigger-1').magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.lightbox-content-1', type: 'inline' } });
$('.lightbox-trigger-2').magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.lightbox-content-2', type: 'inline' } });
$('.lightbox-trigger-3').magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.lightbox-content-3', type: 'inline' } });
$('.lightbox-trigger-4').magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.lightbox-content-4', type: 'inline' } });
$('.lightbox-trigger-5').magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.lightbox-content-5', type: 'inline' } });
$('.lightbox-trigger-6').magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.lightbox-content-6', type: 'inline' } });
$('.lightbox-trigger-7').magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.lightbox-content-7', type: 'inline' } });
$('.lightbox-trigger-8').magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.lightbox-content-8', type: 'inline' } });
$('.lightbox-trigger-9').magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.lightbox-content-9', type: 'inline' } });
$('.lightbox-trigger-10').magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.lightbox-content-10', type: 'inline' } });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a data element to relate the two fields together.  For instance something like.

```
<a href="" class="lightbox-trigger" data-content="lightbox-content-1">Trigger 1</a>

$('.lightbox-trigger').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.magnificPopup({ items: { src: '.'+ $this.data('content'), type: 'inline' } });
});
```

Then all you have to do is make sure they all have the same class, and they all have their data-content set correctly.

If you are unable to add a custom data element to facilitate this logic, optionally you could do an expression to match on multiple elements.

```js
$('[class^="lightbox-trigger-"]').each(function(){
  var triggerClass = Array.prototype.find.call(this.classList, function(clazz){
    return clazz.indexOf('lightbox-trigger-') > -1;
  });
  
  console.log(triggerClass);
  
  var suffix = triggerClass.split('lightbox-trigger-')[1];
  
  console.log(suffix);
  
  var content = '.lightbox-content-'+ suffix;
  
  console.log(content);
  
  //use the content in your method call
  //$(this).magnificPopup({ items: { src: content, type: 'inline' } });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="lightbox-trigger-1 classa"></a>
<a href="" class="lightbox-trigger-2 classb"></a>
<a href="" class="lightbox-trigger-3 classc"></a>
<a href="" class="lightbox-trigger-4 classd"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks @taplar! Unfortunately, I can't add a custom data selector in this situation, only IDs and classes. Is there anyway to get it working with IDs or classes?

Comment: That's very curious.  How are you able to add an id or class, but not a data element?

Comment: In the Divi theme for WordPress. You're only given a Custom ID and Classes as options for each module/element.

Comment: @CharlieWedel alright so the second example shows how you can get the class, break off the suffix you want to use, and then build the selector for you to give to your magnificPopup function call.  I threw an extra class on each of them to show that the code only uses the one that you care about.

Comment: Thank you @taplar! That sounds exactly like what I was looking for. I'm a fairly noob to jQuery and I'm not sure what you mean on that line //use the content in your method call. Where is the magnificPopup called here?

Comment: I left that part out in the second snippet.  Basicly the magnificPopup command you are repeating in your original question, and that I put in the first snippet, you'd do after that //use the content comment

Comment: Thanks @taplar, I will give it a shot and report back. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Good deal.  Glad it's working for ya. (make sure to remove the console logs if you left them in there ^_~)

Comment: side note - I ended up using class*= rather than class^= because Divi puts the user's custom classes after their own classes.

Comment: @CharlieWedel  what do you mean?  `^=` is just the matcher for "starts with" against each class, it doesn't matter what order they are in.  `*=` is the matcher for "contains" which could mean the string is at the beginning, end, or some where in the middle of any of the class names, individually of each other.

Comment: Actually, it's not. The [attribute^=value] selector matches every element whose attribute value begins with a specified value. so in this case, the very first class listed would have to be lightbox-trigger.  [attribute*=value] selector matches any attribute value that contains a specified value as you said, which is all I need for my example.

Comment: Oh snap, good call.  I guess I don't do attribute selectors that much to remember that, >_<

Comment: I know my CSS - just not my jQuery. Thanks for all your help!